# Calculating difference in two time

Tags: java, datetime, calendar

I am calculating the difference between two times and i am able to get the difference in hours and minuted using separate equations,is there any single equation from which i can get hours and minutes at  one go.I am using like:

here diff is the difference between two time value

```
long diffHours1 = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
long min=diff/(60*1000);
```

Comment: What don't use `SimpleDateFormat` class with appropriate pattern such as `hh` or `HH`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure it is helpful here, but [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net) seems to have a little more verbose solution using [Period](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_period.html) e.g.

```
Period p = new Period(startDate, endDate)
int minutes = p.getMinutes(); //returns the left over minutes part
int seconds = p.getSeconds(); //returns the seconds part
```

I'm not sure that for this particular case you need something else than what you have, I agree with aix's

Comment: +1 for Joda time - definitely the best time/data solution for Java

Comment: I think this answer must be accepted answer.(This is my opinion)

Comment: @EranMedan maybe "Java's Date Classes Must Die." title is correct ;) but it is standard now and better approch is using it in `POJO` beans and using utility such as `Joda` or`Date4J` in utility layer ;)

Answer (score 1):

> is there any single equation from which i can get hours and minutes at one go

No, not easily. A Java expression can only have one result; returning several things is not impossible, but would require additional machinery (a wrapper class, a tuple etc). This would result in code that's significantly more complicated than what you have right now.

What you can do to simplify things a little bit is compute minutes first, and then compute hours based on minutes:

```
long diffMinutes = diff / (60*1000);
long diffHours = diffMinutes / 60;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is:

```
String oneGo = (diff / (60 * 60 * 1000)) + " " + (diff / (60 * 1000));
```

:-)

Answer (score 1):

Well, two equations are not that bad (actually using more lines makes it easier to read), although you might change the order, correct the equation and cache some results.

```
diff = //time difference in milliseconds
long diffInMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000);    

//get the number of hours, e.g. 140 / 60 = 2
long hours = diffInMinutes  / 60;

//get the left over minutes, e.g. 140 % 60 = 20
long minutes = diffInMinutes  % 60;
```

If the reason you want one equation is ease of use, try using an alternative library like [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).